Чем можно заменить AssetDatabase в Unity?
Мой скрипт в юнити загружает jpg картинку из папки, но при попытке создать билд, юнити выдает ошибку. Чем можно заменить AssetDatsbase.LoadAssetAtPath?
Resources.Load не подходит, т.к. при создании билда уже нельзя ничего добавлять. А надо, чтобы в битве была папка в которую можно добавить какую-то картинку и она будет использоваться как текстура.
Заранее спасибо.

Ты не можешь ничего добавлять в билд. А AssetDatsbase это класс UnityEditor, его не может быть в билде.

Нужна какая-то замена AssetDatabase, которая не зависит от UnityEditor

PersistentData каталог для хранения загружаемых данных. Работа с файлами System.IO, Unity только даёт путь к каталогу.
